# How do I keep ribs moist during the whole evening? (for my restaurant)

Tags: ribs, restaurant

I'm planning to start serving short ribs in my restaurant.
I'm going to boil the ribs for approx 90 minutes, glaze and oven for 10 minutes, 150 degrees celsius.

But. I want the ribs to stay moist and fresh during the night.

**1. Any ideas on how I can keep my ribs moist?**

**2. I want as short serve time as possible. Best case scenario: no serve time at all so that all cooking is done during the prep before opening.**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the ability to use sous vide?  Sounds like an ideal application for the  tool.

Comment: How about making extra glaze as a sauce and keep the short ribs on a low temp ( either on a sterno type of heater or in a crockpot) or heat them briefly when ordered? This will keep them moist.